# Is the question not clear enough if the reader is not able to grasp what it asks for?

Tags: discussion

After writing some problematic questions myself and after answering downvoted and for closing voted questions I can't get rid of the impression that it is a common practice here that if a reviewer has trouble to immediately within seconds grasp what the question asks for, the reaction to this lack of own understanding is to declare a question as not clear enough or too broad and vote for closing it, where much more constructive were to help the OP to formulate it better so that it fits to the "rules".

There are for sure questions not easy to express clearly especially if they require "a look behind the curtain" or some expertise or just effort in guessing how it could make sense if it doesn't make sense at the first glance. There are often people new to programming who are asking problematic questions because they lack the basics of understanding to clearly see the problem they have. But the same can happen also to experts in case they assume as obvious something that is actual not true.

Another case is if the question asked tries to ask something really new or convey an uncommon idea.

With some effort it is sometimes possible to take a look "behind the curtain" to see what the OP doesn't understand and help on that first. I wrote an answer with which the OP was first not happy at all, but came back some days later to admit that it was the only right answer to give.

I would like to know your opinion what should be the right way to deal with "unclear" or "too broad" questions. Should they have be "banned" immediately or does it make sense to put some more effort in understanding what are they about?

I don't seek an ANSWER here, because it can't be any. I seek a discussion what the goal of this platform is as it will shape it. I think that the only RULES on stackoverflow are these which will make sense to the majority of participants and this is a subject underlying continuous change.

The difference between a good and a bad question could be sometimes only a tiny bit other formulation of the same thing in order not to tap into the pitfalls created by the "rules". To be honest, if the people will fully respect the rules, no question will be asked, because having a question is a clear evidence of not enough effort on the side of the OP ...

I consider here the comment:

> ** Would it be much more constructive to help the OP'? No! It's more constructive to down/close vote and move on quickly to questions that are not unclear. The free time of the skilled and experienced developers/engineers on SO is a limited resource that should be spent wisely. Cleaning up unclear questions should be done by the OP, in response to the signals of down/close votes. – ThingyWotsit**

a clear nice response. So let's close this discussion at this point because if the above said is true, the above statement is a definitive ANSWER so let's don't loose more time on it and move on ...

Comment: This is not a help-desk-platform. This is a Q&A-site. Please understand that the vast majority of this community is not willing to invest a significant amount of time into re-shaping unclear questions. Unclear questions and the like are often a signal for a lack of effort, which in turn results in other users not willing to help the asker.

Comment: @gnat it's fun to see my "question" downvoted as a duplicate of one even more downvoted (-13) . stackoverflow can be sometimes more fun than visiting a a comedy club ... :D .

Comment: @Seth It's not a question of reshaping unclear questions, it's a question of not understanding the question immediately  and therefore asking for it to be closed or downvoting. It seems to me, this is exactly what you have done with this very question.

Comment: @JeremyP It appears that you have not read the question at all. I'd like to ask you to do so. If you've done so, surely you'll agree that "helping the OP formulate his question better in order to fit the rules" is nothing else than reshaping the question. Besides, neither did I downvote this question (*which, just saying, is my own business*) nor did I ask for it to be closed (*as I do not even have the required reputation to do so*).

Comment: @Claudio I'd highly recommend reading through relevant articles regarding the voting system on meta. As you might've noticed you don't lose reputation points when downvoted, which is due to the fact that votes on meta are supposed to reflect the opinion of the voters on the topic, and not - as on the main sites - as reflection of the content-quality.

Comment: ' much more constructive were to help the OP' no,  It's more constructive to down/close vote and move on quickly to questions that are not unclear.  The free time of the skilled and experienced developers/engineers on SO is a limited resource that should be spent wisely. Cleaning up unclear questions should be done by the OP, in response to the signals of down/close votes.

Comment: @Seth I read the question. Yes he mentioned reshaping the question (which I think is not an unreasonable course of action if you have the time to spare) but your comment implies that that is the *only* thing the questioner was talking about and it isn't.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Sorry but who are you to dictate what in SO I spend my time doing? If I wish to spend time helping a questioner improve their question, who are you to tell me not to? Similarly, ifyouI decide it is not worth your time to help somebody to improve their question, nothing here obligates you to do so.

Comment: @JeremyP No, but it is what he suggests as alternative to `simply closing and downvoting`, and that's simply not what we're here for, and as such signalizes a lack of understanding of the fundamental mechanics of Stack Overflow, which is why I felt compelled to elaborate. Regarding the implication: I do not imply that it's the only thing in this post, and the first two sentences are applicable to the question as whole, so, again, I ask you to read carefully through what has been written.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm not dictating.  I have no power or sanction over you.  You don't owe me any money or allegiance or favours.  What I wrote was, inevitably, my view.  You are, of course, free to differ.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit No you don't have power or sanction over me, so stop telling me what I "should" do. There are many ways to improve question quality on this site. Down voting and closing are two and I do not dispute their use when appropriate, but actually helping the questioner improve their question is another and is more friendly and productive in situations where the question superficially appears to be bad but isn't on closer inspection e.g. poor English language skills.

Comment: @JeremyP First you accuse me of not understanding & thus downvoting/closing this question, then you move on and say that I'm at fault due to me implying that his question only deals with reshaping questions, and now you're accusing ThingyWotsit of trying to tell you what to do, which he explicitly denies (rightfully). Of course it's his own opinion, yet what he wrote in his comment is basically community consensus. And, to finish it all off, you repeat what he said and you bring rather pointless arguments. We're not talking about poor language, we're talking about `unclear`/`too broad`.

Comment: @JeremyP 'so stop telling me what I "should" do' is a bad quote.  I had no quote marks round 'should'.  Furthermore, I made my point about the free time of skilled and experienced developers/engineers, not yourself personally.   Nor do I have any particular problem with poor language skills, however, I am fed up with poor/non-existent research/debugging.

Comment: I put quote marks around "should" to emphasize the fact that it was your word and in "The free time of the skilled and experienced developers/engineers on SO is a limited resource that **should** be spent wisely. Cleaning up unclear questions **should** be done by the OP, in response to the signals of down/close votes." [my bolding]  I count myself in the class of skilled and experienced developers/engineers so you were telling me what I should do.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit And I agree with you about poor researching/debugging but not every superficially bad question has poor research and debugging.

Comment: @JeremyP You are free to do whatever you want, as long as you act within your boundaries as user of Stack Overflow. You **should**, however, accept that you're one of several experts that frequent Stack Overflow, and most of these - and the majority of the community, as stated before - agrees with what ThingyWotsit wrote in his comment. If you want to play guessing games with the authors of unclear questions, that's cool, but please don't get angry at other users (*not implying that you do*) if they close the question you're trying to decipher. It's your time & effort that you risk, after all.

Comment: @JeremyP You should read formal meaning of *should* - http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2119.html :). There is slight difference between "should" and "must". From site's point of view spending time on questions that may be useful for single person vs. answering question that likely be found by hundreds people is clear choice - one *should* spent time on better questions. You are in no way prevented from spending your time any way you like (including answering no-research/ unclear/off-topic questions), you are not even required to spend all day on SO.

Comment: The rules you're denouncing right now are why Stack Overflow is so free of [mind-numbingly clueless questions](https://answers.yahoo.com), [memes](https://www.reddit.com), [irrelevant discourse](https://coderanch.com) and other answer-obscuring crap. If you can't stand them then you shouldn't use this site.

Comment: @dorukayhan You have probably misunderstood the message I have tried to convey. The problem on Stack Overflow is that the mind-numb reviewers are not capable to recognize the potential and value of a question if the question asks for something that is outside of their horizon preventing with such behavior the question from reaching the audience it is addressed at. And YES, I don't know how to improve that without the loss on overall quality on the other side ... except raising the level from which reviewers are allowed to review ... but this has also disadvantages ...

Comment: @Claudio No, they're not mind-numb, they're using the appropriate moderation tools correctly in order to make sure that problematic posts are fixed, and that they don't cause problems *until* they are fixed.  Closing questions does not *inhibit* the author from fixing the problems with their question; on the contrary, it *enables* them to do so more effectively than if there were also lots of people posting incorrect or otherwise low quality answers due to the question's lack of clarity.  It also *enables* the question from finding an audience in people looking to help fix it.

Comment: @Claudio Likewise of course it also ensures that people who are only looking for *acceptable* questions that are already answerable, and that aren't interested in spending time helping someone else improve their question, are able to see that this question is not yet ready to be answered, and can know that they shouldn't be looking into it yet.  This is *again* by design, and this is how these tools help direct these questions to the *appropriate* audience.  That *you* want to put bad questions in front of those people, despite their disinterest in seeing them, is *harmful*, not *helpful*.

Comment: @Servy My up to now experience is that there is no space on Stack Overflow for questions with valuable voluminous explanations. The more valuable explanations are there, the less the chance not to receive downvotes and votes for closing. Questions trying to describe something for what there are maybe not yet known concepts available because of the intellectual effort to get the idea about what the question is about don't pass the first stage of review. I have to live with this and find another way to ask them than here on stackoverflow (e.g. concept of "inside out turned file system")

Comment: @Claudio Yes, if you don't actually understand your own question well enough to form a coherent question, and are just looking for unbounded rambling on an unfocused topic, then that is indeed not suited for SO.  By all means, look elsewhere for a place to ask such a question.  SO is for specific, clear, objectively answerable questions.

Comment: @Servy what sometimes looks like "unbounded rambling on an unfocused topic" could be the most brilliant concept looking for appropriate audience to become very popular once established skyrocketing a question to a famous status. It is as it is. I can't change the attitude of others, but I can change my own. From my point of view as stated already in the "question" the discussion here reached the end before your comment appeared triggering me to respond. And from what I understand in what you write I see no chance to get our exchange on a constructive path, so let's move on ...

Comment: @Claudio Sure, anything *could* be made into something of value.  Someone could edit a spam post into something of value, if they really wanted to.  The point remains that if a question, as it sits, isn't appropriate, the best thing for that question is for it to be closed as soon as possible, so that the author can improve it.  If/when the question has been improved such that it is now a great question that's appropriate for the site, and is not longer unclear, unfocused, etc., then it can be reopened.  That's how the system works.

Comment: 'sometimes looks like "unbounded rambling on an unfocused topic" could be the most brilliant concept looking for appropriate audience to become very popular once established skyrocketing a question to a famous status' well, yes, that is possible,  Mr. Occam, however, suggests that it's almost certainly crap.

Comment: I mean, what are the chances that, if it swims on the surface, has webbed feet, waterproof feathers and quacks, it is not a duck?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Mr. Ockham has also famous critics stating: "Entities must not be reduced to the point of inadequacy" and "It is vain to do with fewer what requires more."

Comment: It's a duck!!!!   It's name is Donald and was found on the duckpond.

Answer (score 13):

What you're asking for is not mutually exclusive. When registering a user account and when asking a question, you get plenty of links thrown at you where it is explained what this site is about and how you can write a clear, consise question that others can answer.

If you don't follow that advice and/or don't know how to properly write a question, that question will get downvoted and closevoted. The close message will then contain a message instructing you to clarify the question where possible, again pointing you to the same links.

Sure, it's hard to ask others for help with something of which you can only show a tiny subset, but *everyone* who has ever asked someone else (a teacher, classmate, colleague, friend or stranger on the Internet) for help on something had to realise this. Programming is no single bit different in that regard.

Enough pleas for "compassion", "friendliness" and "effort in guessing how [a question] could make sense" on the site have already been made, and miss the point entirely of what this site is about. It is *not* to hand-hold beginning programmers into both learning to program *and* learning to ask others for help; there are not enough people in the world for that.

So to answer your title:

> Is the question not clear enough if the reader is not able to grasp what it asks for?

In general, yes, granted the reader has some experience in the subject of the question. We definitely shouldn't be answering based on your guess what the OP meant.